# mongoldb query performance optimisation

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following document structure in my `store` collection,

```
{
  "_id": "some_custom_id",
  "inventory": [
    {
      "productId": "some_prod_id",
      // ...restAttributes
    },
    // 500+ such items
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to make a query `coll.find({_id:"some_id","inventory.productId":"some_prod_id"},{...})`

The query sometimes takes a lot of time to return(10 secs or so). so I created an index `{_id:1,"inventory.productId":1}` but still no performance gain, so I tried mongo [query explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain) and found that `_id` index is used and not the one I created. Then I created another index `{"inventory.productId":1, _id:1}`still no luck.

Here is the output of `coll.find({_id:"some_id","inventory.productId":"some_prod_id"}).explain("executionStats")`

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "somedb.Stores",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "$eq" : "114"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "inventory.productId" : {
                        "$eq" : "41529689"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "inventory.productId" : {
                    "$eq" : "41529689"
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_id_",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "_id" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "_id" : [ 
                        "[\"114\", \"114\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "inventory.productId" : {
                    "$eq" : "41529689"
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 2,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 1,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 2,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_id_",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "_id" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "_id" : [ 
                        "[\"114\", \"114\"]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 1,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "somecluster-shard-00-02-1jury.gcp.mongodb.net",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.0.16",
        "gitVersion" : "2a5433168a53044cb6b4fa8083e4cfd7ba142221"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1585112231, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1585112231, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "joFIiOgu32NHAVrAO40lHKl7/i8=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(6778940624956555265)
        }
    }
}
```

so I have 2 questions,

1. How do I increase the query performance?
2. I see indexes `{"inventory.productId":1, _id:1}` and `{_id:1,"inventory.productId":1}` are having different size. what is the difference between them?

Comment: What is the version of MongoDB you are using? Also, please post the _query plan_ generated using the `explain("executionStats").`.

Comment: @prasad_ I have updated the question with query plan, I'm using `4.0.16` mongoldb version.

Comment: Your query plan says it is using the default index on the `_id` field ("indexName" : "_id_"),. Also, the other indexes are _not_ used. The "executionStats": ... has "executionTimeMillis" : 0. So, what is the issue? Tell how many documents are there in the collection?

Comment: The problem is, as mentioned in the question some times query takes a lot of time to respond, "executionTimeMillis" was low because no concurrent operation was happening when I executed the query, execution time increases even if there are 10 concurrent operations to mongo cluster.I have around 500 records with each having 500 items inside inventory array.
I'm using m30 mongo atlas cluster and I have enough resources on server side. @prasad_

Comment: Then, you have to investigate further those concurrent operations and their resources usage. It is not related to this collection or the query (I think, as per the query plan output).

Comment: I have other aggregation queries running on the same collection(concurrently) and they use both `_id` and `inventory.productId` in their `match` stage, I came across this [presentation](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/mongodbpresentationfinal-151124162151-lva1-app6891/95/mongodb-internals-27-638.jpg?cb=1448382277) where it says `mongo aggregation is single threaded`, are these aggravations causing find query to perform poorly? @prasad_

Comment: Using the `_id` field for different queries or an index created on a collection used with multiple queries is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sometimes Mongo chooses the wrong index, Basically Mongo does a mini "race" between available indexes and chooses the one that fetches 101 documents first.

   Obviously this does not necessarily mean the best index was chosen. like in your case, to avoid this you can use [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/), this forces Mongo to use the index of your choice which will make the query run much faster.
2. Mongo builds its indexes as a [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), due to the nature of data distribution the trees are built differently and have other sizes.
   Theres an interesting and more in-depth explanation about how they build indexes in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_YKRnbpRF0) video. but without diving into the source code this will remain a "black box" to you.

Comment: I used `hint` with my query and now the new index is being used but still most of the times performance is lower the the query that uses `_id` index. 
also the query without hint doesn't seem to be running a `race` between indexes, as queryPlanner's rejectedPlans is empty(attached to the question).